# The rank of a symmetric matrix equals the number of nonzero eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I am wondering why

> the rank of a symmetric matrix equals its number of nonzero
>   eigenvalues.

I have tried showing it like this:

A symmetrix matrix A can be written:

$$A=PDP^T$$, where P is an orthogonal matrix.

It is not difficult to see that for a vector x: $PDP^Tx=0 \leftrightarrow DP^Tx=0$, 
since P is invertible.

So what we need to show is that dimension of the nullspace of $DP^T$ equals the number of eigenvalues with value zero.

Do you see how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of $D$ and it is clear that the rank of $D$ equals the number of nonzero eigenvalues (which are the same eigenvalues as those of $A$).

Comment: But how do we know that the rank of A is equal to the rank of D?

Comment: Because two similar matrices have the same rank.

Comment: @user394334 Because multiplying with an invertible matrix doesn't affect rank. You've already seen that that's true for multiplying with $P$ from the left. It's not very difficult to show that it also holds for multiplying with $P^T$ from the right.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, I would say that the rank of a symmetric matrix is equal to the sum of the geometric multiplicities of its nonzero eigenvalues.
For example, If $A$ has two nonzero eigenvalues, say $2$ and $3$, with geometric multiplicities $1$ and $2$ respectively, then the rank of $A$ is $1+2 = 3$.

In this example, $2$ and $3$ would appear once and twice in $D$ respectively. So the number of repetitions of nonzero eigenvalues in $D$ needs to be considered