# Number of nonzero eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A∈R^{n×n}$ be a symmetric matrix. The rank of $A$ is defined to be the dimension of the range of $A$.

Now I want to know how this is equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ by using the representation of $A$ as $S∧S^T$.

I have checked a similar post ([The rank of a symmetric matrix equals the number of nonzero eigenvalues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299724)) but I still don't have a clue.

Can someone explain this step by step?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe My guess is that $\wedge$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Hint: what would be the rank of the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix then it is a diagonalizable matrix and the diagonal form of this matrix has each eigenvalues on each column of the matrix.

The rank of a matrix is the number of column linear independant that means, column of the matrix wouldn't be a linear sum of others colums.

Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$
If $\lambda = 0$ then, we have in the matrix, a column with only $0$ and this column would be either column $\times 0$ so this column would be linear dependant.

If $\lambda \neq 0 $ then the column of the diagonal matrix with $\lambda$ couldn't be written as a linear combination of others column.

So the rank of $A$ is the number of column that are linear independant, that means for a matrix symmetric (for a diagonalizable matrix) the number of nonzero eigenvalues